# Why the evaluateJavaScript works only once?

Tags: qt4, webkit, pyqt, web-crawler, qtwebkit

I am writing an crawler to crawl images, which needs to programmatically click a menu to turn to the next page. Here is my code whenever a page finish loading:

```
public slots:

void nextPage()
{
    mainFrame()->evaluateJavaScript("readweb.nextPage()");
}
```

After click, the mainFrame should load a new url point to the next webpage(which contains image I want to crawl). But I find it **works only for the first** time. After the first click, the second click didn't lead to a new url loading.The js scripts of the webpage has already loaded,and only load for one time.

Why it doesn't work? Anyone has similar situation?

Answer (score 1):

I have soemthing similar, but it does not only work once, it works just every second call.

My workaround for now is a fake call like: `webframe.evaluateJavaScript('return true;')`

This forces to fail (return outside a function) and the next call will work as it should.

I don't know if this failing call will reset the engine or what realy happens.

Answer (score 1):

Dont know if it matters or not, but you are missing a semicolon at the end of your statement?